# plugins not working in android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

For some reason that i am not sure of plugins are not being called when running on android. It does however work on IOS which makes it all the more difficult to determine to problem, i have looked at the console log and the android logs but there are no calls to any of the plugins. The content on the page though does load

the plugins installed are

```
"installed_plugins": {
    "com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": ""
    },
    "nl.x-services.plugins.calendar": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": ""
    },
    "org.apache.cordova.dialogs": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": ""
    },
    "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": ""
    },
    "com.boyvanderlaak.cordova.plugin.orientationchanger": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": ""
    }
},
```

android seems to be adding them to the build and they are loading into cache but i can't make any calls to them.

I am using Phonegap/Cordova 3.4.0 and building for Android 4.4.2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If  you  are  building  an application  in phonegap  you can use the command line  tools  to  add  the  required plugin like this 
  plugins are  stored in the repository  you can  use this

```
 $ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

or you can go  for repository 
here

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git
```

Answer (score 1):

After much search i figured it out apparently if some of you plugins are only designed for particular platforms like iOS's StatusBar or Android's orientation changer plugins you need to add them in as a feature otherwise other plugins don't seem to load properly.

Example for iOS

```
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
</feature>
```

Example for iOS

```
<feature name="OrientationChanger">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.boyvanderlaak.cordova.plugin.orientationchanger.OrientationChanger" />
</feature>
```

Hopefully this help anyone else with the same problem